# How to simplify the record syntax with pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

I've just finished reading *Learn You a Haskell* and I've started to experiment on my own. I just wanted to create a very simple game system where player A can attack player B.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. My `autoAttack` function was very daunting to write. How could I improve it?
2. How would I format my `autoAttack` function correctly? I don't find it very pleasing to read.

```
main = print $ createActor `autoAttack` createActor
type Vector2= (Float,Float)
type Vector3 = (Float,Float,Float)
data StatsSystem = StatsSystem {physicalDamage :: Float,
                                spellPower     :: Float,
                                health         :: Float,
                                mana           :: Float,
                                attackRange    :: Float,
                                castRange      :: Float,
                                attackSpeed    :: Float
                               } deriving(Show)

data MovementSystem = MovementSystem {direction :: Vector2,
                                      speed     :: Float,
                                      position  :: Vector3
                                     } deriving(Show)
data Actor = Actor {stats :: StatsSystem,
                    ms    :: MovementSystem
                   } deriving(Show)
createActor :: Actor
createActor = Actor {stats = StatsSystem {physicalDamage = 1.0,
                                          spellPower = 1.0,
                                          health = 10.0,
                                          mana = 1.0,
                                          attackRange = 1.0,
                                          castRange = 1.0,
                                          attackSpeed = 1.0
                                         },
                     ms = MovementSystem{direction = (1.0,1.0),
                                         speed = 50.0,
                                         position = (0,0,0)
                                        }
                    }
autoAttack :: Actor -> Actor -> Actor
autoAttack Actor {stats = StatsSystem {physicalDamage = p,
                                       spellPower = _,
                                       health = _,
                                       mana = _,
                                       attackRange = _,
                                       castRange = _,
                                       attackSpeed = _
                                      },
                   ms = m
                 } 
           Actor {stats = s2,
                   ms = m2
                 } 
           = Actor {stats = StatsSystem {physicalDamage = physicalDamage s2,
                                         spellPower = spellPower s2,
                                         health = health s2 - p,
                                         mana = mana s2,
                                         attackRange = attackRange s2,
                                         castRange = castRange s2,
                                         attackSpeed = attackSpeed s2
                                        },
                    ms = m2
                   }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, when you are not using fields in a record, you don't have to use _ to mark that they should be ignored;  you only need to include the fields in the pattern that you are actually using.

Second, it is possible to update a couple of fields in a record without respecifying the whole thing from scratch.  If `x` is the name of the old record and you want to set the field `a` to 42 and `b` to 24, then the expression `x { a = 42, b = 24 }` is equal to the record `x` with `a` set to 42 and `b` set to 24.

Putting these ideas together, `autoAttack` could be rewritten like so:

```
autoAttack :: Actor -> Actor -> Actor
autoAttack actor@(Actor {stats = stats@(StatsSystem {physicalDamage = p, health = h}})) =
    actor {stats = stats { health = h - p } }
```

Where we have used the syntax `actor@(Actor ..)` to bind the `Actor` to the name `actor`, which is a useful pattern for when you want to both pattern match on an argument and also have access to its value.

---

Just to be clear, it is worth mentioning that, because data is immutable, changing a couple of fields involves making a full copy of the data structure.  (Thanks to Daniel Wagner for bringing this up).

Comment: To be precise: it is in fact _not_ possible (in GHC) to update a couple of fields in a record without rebuilding the whole thing from scratch; however, there is a bit of syntax sugar (which you described well) that makes describing how to rebuild it more palatable than listing the new value of every single field.

Comment: You are right, I can see how my wording might be confusing.  I changed "rebuilding" to "respecifying" and added an end note.

Answer (score 5):

Two things that can help clean a lot of stuff up are the `lens` library and the `RecordWildCards` language extension.

`RecordWildCards` allows you to set record fields in a very declarative fashion.  See the changes to `createActor` to get an idea of how that can help.

The various functions in `lens` help a lot when manipulating nested records.  `autoAttack` becomes much shorter and easier to read (once you've gotten used to the various `lens` combinators).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import Control.Lens

data StatsSystem = StatsSystem {
    _physicalDamage :: Float
  , _spellPower     :: Float
  , _health         :: Float
  , _mana           :: Float
  , _attackRange    :: Float
  , _castRange      :: Float
  , _attackSpeed    :: Float
  } deriving Show

data MovementSystem = MovementSystem {
    _direction :: (Float, Float)
  , _speed     :: Float
  , _position  :: (Float, Float, Float)
  } deriving Show

data Actor = Actor {
    _stats :: StatsSystem
  , _ms    :: MovementSystem
  } deriving Show 

makeLenses ''Actor
makeLenses ''StatsSystem
makeLenses ''MovementSystem

createActor :: Actor
createActor = Actor StatsSystem {..} MovementSystem {..} where
  _physicalDamage = 1.0
  _spellPower     = 1.0
  _health         = 10.0
  _mana           = 1.0
  _attackRange    = 1.0
  _castRange      = 1.0
  _attackSpeed    = 1.0
  _direction      = (1.0, 1.0)
  _speed          = 50.0
  _position       = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

autoAttack :: Actor -> Actor -> Actor
autoAttack a0 a1 = a1&stats.health -~ a0^.stats.physicalDamage
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm being a bit primitive here, but what's wrong with a couple of helper functions?

```
punchStrength a = physicalDamage $ stats a
-- or...
-- punchStrength = physicalDamage.stats


hurtActor a amt = a { stats = (stats a) { health = old_health - amt } }
    where old_health = health $ stats a

autoAttack a0 a1 = hurtActor a1 (punchStrength a0)
```

I'll grant you that the record syntax in hurtActor is a bit ugly, but the lens stuff isn't a huge improvement what with its 9 million line-noise operators.

Comment: They grow on you. ;)